# Trying to create a program that lets user create as many lists as he/she wants

Tags: python-2.7

I'm supposed to create a program that allows a user to create as many lists as he wants and also as many items in each of the lists as he/she wants. It will then save the lists to a .txt file This is my code. It asks for the names of the lists just fine but I don't know how to input the items into the lists or save it to a .txt file

```
import os

list_number = int(input("How many lists do you want to create? "))

for i in range(int(list_number)):
    name = raw_input(str("List name: "))

for j in list:
    items = input(str("List items: "))
```

Comment: Google search: `list.append()`, `open()`, `write()`.

Comment: If you're just learning python, I'd seriously recommend using python3: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Thanks or the comment. Sorry for the late reply. I already figured it out with python 3. Although, my school was teaching us with python 2.